# Django Celery Beat Periodic Tasks

Tags: python, django, django-celery, celerybeat, periodic-task

I am trying to run a periodic task with django celery, and it is dynamically added by users using custom arguments. I have the following code to start the task. I only want it to run once as it takes a while for it to set up, and I have an infinite while loop that constantly checks for changes on a website.

```
schedule, created = IntervalSchedule.objects.get_or_create(every=100,period=IntervalSchedule.DAYS,)
PeriodicTask.objects.create(interval=schedule, enabled=True, name=name,task='scanner.tasks.texting', args=json.dumps([phone_number, carrier_address]),)
```

The problem is that when I create the task, it is not started and needs to wait for the interval before starting. Is it possible to start the tasks when the object is created?

Otherwise, I could change the interval to just a second to start immediately. The problem with this implementation is that it will start the thread every second, even though I just want to run it once, and let it keep running in the background.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: You could start the task on the post_save signal maybe?

Comment: sorry, how exactly would i do this?

Comment: Read this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/signals/

Answer (score 0):

You can just run the function in the background immediately:

```py
scanner.tasks.texting.delay([phone_number, carrier_address])
```

and then add periodic task:

```py
schedule, created = IntervalSchedule.objects.get_or_create(every=100,period=IntervalSchedule.DAYS,)
PeriodicTask.objects.create(interval=schedule, enabled=True, name=name,task='scanner.tasks.texting', args=json.dumps([phone_number, carrier_address]),)
```

The other solution might be to [dynamically update periodic task](https://saasitive.com/tutorial/dynamically-update-periodic-tasks-celery/). For example start periodic task with small interval and after the execution update the task, ideally task can be updated at the end of the first execution:

```py
# you need additional object to keep reference to PeriodicTask

class ModelWithTask(models.Model):
    task = models.OneToOneField(
        PeriodicTask, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )

# start with SECONDS interval

some_object = ModelWithTask.objects.get_or_create()

schedule, created = IntervalSchedule.objects.get_or_create(every=100,period=IntervalSchedule.SECONDS,)
task = PeriodicTask.objects.create(interval=schedule, enabled=True, name=name,task='scanner.tasks.texting', args=json.dumps([phone_number, carrier_address, some_object.id]),)

some_object.task = task
some_object.save()
```

##### Update task

```py
# in scanner.tasks.texting

new_schedule, created = IntervalSchedule.objects.get_or_create(every=100,period=IntervalSchedule.DAYS,)

some_object.task.interval = new_schedule
some_object.task.save()
```